# How to check if promiscuous mode is enabled on network interface in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, networking, packet-sniffer

I'm working with basic windump commands. After I close the windump, my pc is slowly and cpu range is high. How to check if promiscuous mode is enabled on network interface in windows server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell.

Get-NetAdapter | Format-List -Property PromiscuousMode

That'll give you true or false.

Comment: I'd add the property `ifAlias` in case he has more than one interface

`Get-NetAdapter | Format-List -Property ifAlias,PromiscuousMode`

Comment: Makes good sense - nice catch.